# Python Google API resource limit error

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, google-api

I understand the resource limit, and that you can just wait it out and go again.
So I made a code that runs until the limit is hit, then waits 6 minutes, runs again, etc. Just to test the time limit.

Well sometimes that 6 minutes is enough, sometimes not. I need a consistent way to beat this resource limit.

```
counter=0
try:
    for i in range(5000): # high enough to break limit
        client.open(google_sheet).sheet1
        counter+=1
        sleep(.02)
        print counter
except Exception as e:
    print "ERROR"
    if re.search('"code": 429', str(e)): #confirms error is due to resource limit
        sleep(360)
        for i in range(5000): 
            sheets_of_months[1].sheet_object
            counter+=1
            sleep(.02)
            print counter
```

I have it run until the error appears, wait 6 minutes, run again. The printing is just to avoid any pointless waiting.

Thanks for reading and thanks for any and all responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I figured it out, after reading around and just giving hours for different codes to run. So [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361060/is-googles-documentation-on-exponential-backoff-inconsistent) really helped me when as I also noticed the posts by Google were inconsistent. But the answer pointed something out I needed to think on.

"The important part about the algorithm is that its exponential, and not about the number of tries."

Googles doc says to stop after like 16 seconds and just log it.

So I tried a few answers to this,

1. I started with increasing the sleep time before trying to reload the page. Up to 20 minutes worth even, and sometimes it still wouldn't work. But sometimes 30 seconds is enough.
2. I tried adding random amount of seconds on to the sleep amount to keep it different and random as suggested in the docs, but I believe this is more for networking opposed to one program and one sheet communicating, and no other machines expected to interfere.
3. I tried changing pages, maybe the page I was opening is locked since I hit the resource limit on it.

I basically made a small while loop that just goes time and time again and when it works it prints how long it took for the resource limit to cool down. I tested with each of these variables at times and came to the following conclusion.

The page you are trying to open never locks, there's no need to switch pages, while it appeared to work for me for a bit, it was just luck. Further research proved it useless.

Sometimes it will just say you're still at the limit, whether or not this is due to the fact that it somehow tries opening the file in preparation during the sleep or not, idk. All I know is that 20 minutes of sleeping, and it would still say I'm at the limit.

The random integer while probably useful for networking issues to prevent requests from bundling, was not an issue for me. So excess code, meaning get rid of it.

This loop I made averages out around 30 seconds and sometimes a minute. But does the job. Thanks to all who read and cared to look at the post. I hope I explained my thought process well and helped in some way for the community.

```
times_page_opened=0
amount_of_seconds_iterating= 2
while True:
    counter=0 
    try:
        for i in range(5000):
            counter+=1
            if counter==2: # This confirms that it has opened a page again at least once already, meaning the limit has reset.
                print "Had to wait %s seconds" % (amount_of_seconds_iterating) # This prints the amount of seconds in the iteration that it took.
                amount_of_seconds_iterating= 2 # This just resets the iteration to 2 seconds for next time.
            client.open(google_sheet).sheet1 # This just opens the actual page.
            times_page_opened+=1
            sleep(.02)
            print times_page_opened # This helps me keep track of how many times the code has succesfully opened the page.
    except Exception as e:
        print "ERROR" # Tells me the code is waiting because it hit the error.
        amount_of_seconds_iterating*=2 # Doubles the waiting time.
        try:
            if re.search('"code": 429', str(e)): # Confirms that it is infact the resource limit error.
                sleep(amount_of_seconds_iterating)
                client.open(google_sheet).sheet1 # Attempts again to re-open the page.
        except:
            print "Double Error"
```

Once implemented and simplified, it looked like this.

```
def reset_limit():
    iteration= 2
    while True:
        try:
            client.open('Chem Sheet Summary Report DO NOT DELETE').sheet1
            return
        except:
            iteration*=2
            sleep(iteration)
```

To use it, I would try doing whatever action I would run into, and if it hits the resource limit, it will call the reset_limit function which will only return once the resource limit has reset, like so.

```
while True:
    try:
        client.open(google_sheet).sheet1
    except Exception as e:
        if re.search('"code": 429', str(e)):
            reset_limit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Google suggested way to manage the quota limit is to implement requests with an [exponential backoff logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff). I do recommend to review this documentation (by Google):

- [Handling API Errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#429_too_many_requests)
- [Implementing Exponential Backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#exponential-backoff)

If you look you can find different libraries helping you with the exponential backoff:

- [Retrying](https://github.com/rholder/retrying) (no longer maintained, but still good)
- [Tenacity](https://github.com/jd/tenacity)

Looking at your code, using tenacity what you could do is:

```
import tenacity


# Wait 2^x * 0.5 seconds between each retry, up to 60 seconds
# 60 seconds afterwards.
# Stops after 30 attempts
@tenacity.retry(stop=tenacity.stop_after_attempt(30),
                wait=tenacity.wait_exponential(multiplier=0.5, max=60))
def call_with_exponential_backoof(client, google_sheet):
    client.open(google_sheet).sheet1
```

Comment: Sadly I've read and implemented the exponential back off from Google and it didn't help, this is beause my quota limit is every 100 seconds supposedly. But when I wait over 6 minutes it still wont work sometimes. I have tried adding the random amount of milliseconds, no difference sadly.

Comment: I've tried to improve my answer with an example using tenacity.